# Elasticsearch conditional filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to filter out documents with some kind of conditional logic (I think), but I can't get this working.

My documents are like this:

`{type: 'A'}
{type: 'B', foo: ['bar']}
{type: 'B', foo: []}`

Now I need to filter out all documents of `type` 'B' where `foo` is empty.
In pseudocode the query would be:

`if(type == 'B' && foo == []) {
  // filter out this document
}`
 
My main query looks like this:

`query: {
  filtered: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: {
          match_all: []
        }
      }
    },
    filter: {
      bool:{
        must_not: {
          term: {'_hidden': true}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Elasticsearch Version is 1.5.0

Comment: Elasticsearch does not store empty fields. I guess that you are talking about a field that does not exists, right? Could you use a exists filter inside a must_not? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-exists-filter.html
did you try?

Comment: Hi @WaldemarNeto. Yes, I did try to use an `exists` and/or `missing` filter. 
That does work for all documents of type 'B'. but it also filters all documents of type 'A', because there is never a "property" foo.

Comment: Just to understand, if type == "A" foo does not matter, right? and if type == "B" foo need to be empty?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your questions. 
If type == 'A' foo doesn't matter, because there is no foo, if type == 'B' foo need NOT to be empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood, is that?
if type == a, all documents that have a will return.
And if type == b and the field foo is not there they will return, make sense?

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "should": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "type": "a"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                      "bool": {
                          "must": [
                             {
                                 "term": {
                                    "type": "b"
                                 }
                             }
                          ],
                          "must_not": [
                             {
                                 "missing": {
                                    "field": "foo"
                                 }
                             }
                          ]
                      }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to exclude type b documents which have a missing foo field not include them in the results.

Comment: That is correct. And additionally I don't really care about the type of the other documents. There may be many different types. All I want is to exclude the documents of type 'B' where 'foo' is missing.